# Position text under each other and stretch

Tags: css

Here is my CSS code;

```
#nav a {
  display:block;
  background: #1a1a1a; 
  color: #fff; 
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: static;
  float:left;

  }
```

Here is the problem:

[image]

I'm trying to make each item have it's own line (on the image you can see re-tweets and likes are on the same line), when they should be on a separate line. Also, as you can see by looking at the re-tweets and likes background, it doesn't stretch to the red border because the text isn't long enough. How would I make the background stretch to the border width? Here is more code used for this section;

```
  /* submenu positioning*/
  #nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -99999em;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #A81E1E;

}
```

Another example of the background not stretching:

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please, post a demo.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's all the code that I can find that when I make edits to, it edits the section. Apart from that the only thing I can do is post the whole CSS which is about 50 lines of code.

https://socialstamp.me.uk/new/login.php - Will need to login with these details - Username: stacktest Password: stacktest - Once logged in click here to see the issue: https://socialstamp.me.uk/new/dashboard.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `dsiplay:block` to the `li`.

```
#nav li {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto !important;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you for your answer. Problem solved.